# Return all sets where all of its numbers are not in any other set

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, set

I recently had to solve the following algorithm question, which it confused me.

> Suppose you have an array of sets that contain integers. Write a
>   function that returns all sets where all of its numbers are not in any
>   other set.
>
> EXAMPLE {0,4,9}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8}
>
> RESULT {6,7,8}

The code should be in Objective-C or Swift.

**[EDIT]**

I came up so far with something like that but can't really finish it.

```
- (NSArray*) getDisjointedSets:(NSArray*)sets {
    NSArray* resultedSet;
    NSMutableArray* indexDoesntExistInSets = [NSMutableArray array];
    [sets enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSArray* nextIndexArray = [sets objectAtIndex:idx+1];
        NSNumber* numberIndex = obj;
        [nextIndexArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSNumber* numberNextIndex = obj;
            if (numberIndex.intValue == numberNextIndex.intValue) {
               // number exists in the next set, continue

               *stop = YES;;
            } else {
                [indexDoesntExistInSets addObject:numberIndex];
            }
        }];
    }];
    return resultedSet;
}
```

Comment: What's you question? What have you tried? What issue are you having? Or do you just want someone to give you the code?

Comment: That's the question above, I couldn't solve it, so I'm seeking for the answer to understand it.

Comment: Post what you tried and explain what issue you are having.

Comment: Edited with some code that I'm trying to complete.

Comment: Is there any bound on the numbers in the sets? The number of sets?

Comment: No, there is no other requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code iterates the array of arrays. But then you get the next array, iterate its numbers but try to compare each of those numbers against the current set.

Assuming you have an `NSArray` of `NSArray` objects, you can do this:

```
- (NSArray *)getDisjointedSets:(NSArray *)sets {
    NSMutableArray *resultSet = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSArray *arrayA in sets) {
        BOOL noMatch = YES;
        for (NSArray *arrayB in sets) {
            // Skip if both are the same array
            if (arrayA != arrayB) {
                NSMutableSet *setA = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:arrayA];
                NSSet *setB = [NSSet setWithArray:arrayB];
                [setA intersectSet:setB];
                if (setA.count) {
                    // The two sets have something in common
                    noMatch = NO;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (noMatch) {
            [resultSet addObject:arrayA];
        }
    }

    return resultSet;
}
```

Test code:

```
NSArray *sets = @[
    @[ @0, @4, @9 ],
    @[ @3, @4, @5 ],
    @[ @6, @7, @8 ]
];
NSArray *result = [self getDisjointedSets:sets];
NSLog(@"results = %@", result);
```

Comment: It works great! I was missing the key to iterate every set to the A set, skip if it's the same one and use intersect! Thanks.